# Getting a negative number for a long

Tags: java

I am using this hashing algorithm..

```
public long DEKHash(String str)
   {
      long hash = str.length();

      for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
      {
         hash = ((hash << 5) ^ (hash >> 27)) ^ str.charAt(i);
      }

      return hash;
   }
```

I have modified it slightly so that it produces a larger number. But this number is larger than a long and then overflows and becomes negative. I am beginning Java and wanted to know if it is possible to get the real value?

I was looking into `BigInteger` but I am not having any luck with it.

Comment: The point of a hash is to be fixed size (and usually a lot shorter than the input). What you want is possible, but your method should then not be named 'hash', as that would have nothing whatsoever to do with one. In general it sounds like you're a bit confused; you _DO_ very much want a fixed size. Numbers can be negative, what's the problem with this?

Comment: The size of the data going in is 36 bytes and will always be 36. The result is a negative on Java because it goes beyond the bound of max value for long. I have the same code running in C which supports unsigned long long and thus I am getting the correct value.

Comment: Java does not support whole number values over 64 bits. `BigInteger` is a possibility if you can stand the overhead. Sounds like an XY problem.  What is it you are really trying to do with this value that requires it to be positive?

Comment: Of course it does, you'd be left-shifting by 5 a total of 36 times, that's 180 bits, _well_ past long's 64 bits.

Comment: With that kind of reasoning then I guess a byte also supports 180 bits or even more.

Comment: When running the same code in C I get a positive number. A number that I am expecting to get. When I run the same thing on Java I get a negative. I cannot compare the negative number in Java to the positive number in C. I need the Java number to match what is found in C.

Comment: For `long` 'val', try `BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(Long.toUnsignedString(val));` if you want it to correspond to your unsigned C value

Comment: @xf9000  One problem you may be having is the right shift.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will solve your problem. Use `Long.unsignedCompare()`.

```
long a1 = 1;
long a2 = -1;

if (a2 < a1) {
    // a2 is less which is what you would expect
    System.out.println(a2);
}

if (Long.compareUnsigned(a1,a2) < 0) {
    // here, a1 is less
    System.out.println(a1);
}
```

prints

```
-1
1
```

Also, above you have

```
hash = ((hash << 5) ^ (hash >> 27)) ^ str.charAt(i);
```

Did you know that `>>` extends the sign bit to the right.  If you want to just right shift and not extend (i.e. fill with 0 bits, then do `>>>`)